# Intelij highlight python import in red even if it exist and works

Tags: python, intellij-idea, anaconda3, code-inspection

I have a problem with usage of Python in Intelij - at code inspection it highlight some imports with red (Unresolved reference) even if the package is installed and the code is compilable. As a context, in Intelij I use the Pyhton [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/631-python), and the project is linked with anaconda (in order to execute the code). Again, the scikit learn package is installed, the code execute well; python version is 3.8.5, conda version is 22.9.0

Here is an image:
[image]

Comment: This looks related to the following bug - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-344500

Try upgrading to the latest 2023.3.6 and see if the issue persists